# Is it bad to use conditional rendering for MUI Drawer components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using Material UI's drawer to slide out many different components, like pages, for my react app. I have maybe 10 different drawers and they are essentially like mini pages that overlay almost the entire screen, just that my app wants to be a literal SPA so thus there is no routing to a different page. Here is an example of 1 such drawer:

```
<Drawer             
     open={openAssetManagement}
    {/* other stylings and properties */}
             
     >
    <AssetManagement />  // the component that slides out  
</Drawer>
```

The drawers are all under 1 common parent component, and I noticed that the Drawers are being re-rendered in the background even if they are not open (due to either props change, or the parent component re-rendering occasionally).

How can I prevent this for performance purposes? Is it bad to use the same variable openAssetManagement and conditionally render the entire Drawer? Eg
`{openAssetManagement && ( // the Drawer code here )}`

I am just trying to be careful if there are any unwanted side effects to introduce so many conditional rendering for large components.

Comment: There's no need to optimize for it as it won't trigger 'paint' due to the fact its being outside the screen.
If the element is properly managed, i.e only being updated by the direct state it consumes, then you shouldn't have any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open/close the Drawer like this `{openAssetManagement && <Drawer open {...}/>}`, it will show/hide without an animation.

Otherwise

```
   <Drawer open={openAssetManagement}>
       <AssetManagement />
   </Drawer>
```

This way React calls `createElement` on Drawer and its children (N times, once per child) on each render, even if they are not used.

Usually this is not a big problem, unless the children content is not so big.  If so, you can move the children in new component so the Drawer gets single child only. That way React will call `createElement` only twice, once for the Drawer and once for its single child, on each render

Or you can try conditionally render the children only

```
  <Drawer open={openAssetManagement}>
       {openAssetManagement && <AssetManagement />}
  </Drawer>
```

In most cases that wouldn't matter. It will be enough optimized

Comment: Thank you! the conditionally render the children method is a great idea i didnt think of.